# Android Mockito Test on Activity's method which shows alert dialog

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I am new to the Mockito Android Test framework. I have written one method in the activity and which shows the AlertDialog and I am writing test cases for that method.

Here are the functions of the activity which shows the alert dialog box:

```
fun showDialogBox(
         shortMessage: String?,
         longMessage: String?,
         progress: Int,
         status: String?
     ) {
         runOnUiThread {

             if (cdfwExtractionStatusAlertDialog == null) {

                 val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                     R.layout.cdfw_extraction_status_layout,
                     null
                 )

                 val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                     .setView(mDialogView)
                     .setCancelable(false)

                 shortMessageTv = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.short_message_tv)
                 longMessageTv = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.long_message_tv)
                 closeButton = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.close_button)
                 cdfwProcessBar = mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)

                 cdfwProcessBar.progress = progress

                 shortMessageTv.text = shortMessage
                 longMessageTv.text = longMessage

                 closeButton.setOnClickListener {
                     cdfwExtractionStatusAlertDialog?.dismiss()
                 }

                 checkStatus(status)
                 cdfwExtractionStatusAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
             } else {
                 shortMessageTv.text = longMessage
                 longMessageTv.text = longMessage
                 cdfwProcessBar.progress = progress
                 checkStatus(status)
             }
         }
    }
```

Here are my mockito test cases for the same function:

```
@Test
    public void testCDFWExtractionStatusNoZipFound(){
        MainActivity activity = Mockito.mock(MainActivity.class);
        activity.showDialogBox("","CDFW Required.",0,"FAILED_NO_ZIP_FOUND");
        Mockito.matches("CDFW Extraction Status");
        Mockito.matches("CDFW Required.");
        Mockito.matches("Close");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCDFWExtractionStatusInProgress(){
        MainActivity activity = Mockito.mock(MainActivity.class);
        activity.showDialogBox("","CDFW extraction ongoing",0,"IN_PROGRESS");
        Mockito.matches("CDFW Extraction Status");
        Mockito.matches("CDFW extraction ongoing");
    }
```

It shows the test passed successfully but I am not sure whether this is the right way to write test cases for the same function if this is the wrong method then how do I write a test case for the same function.

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing your UI it is better to use instrumented testing.

Instrumentation testing is testing that runs on Physical devices, so, in your case, the test will run in a real device or emulator to check if the flow is right.

For that, you can use Espresso, which is a framework provided by AndroidX.

For more detail, please check this out:
[Test UI for a single app](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing)

Now, why not use Mockito for UI testing?

When you are testing the UI, you have to ensure the right flows to the user and good interaction. You can mock the scenario, but you can't test the whole flow because you don't know how it will behave when, for example, a click is made in a different place than the one you are testing on.

If you want to test for example that your Alert Dialog is shown, you can use:

```
@Test
fun testCDFWExtractionStatusNoZipFound() {
    //..
    onView(withId(R.id.dialogId)).check(matches(allOf(withText("CDFW Required"), isDisplayed()));
    //..
}
```